# Debugging Outlook Folder Web Page

Tags: debugging, outlook

How can I debug web page issues that only occur in the Outlook "Folder Web Page" browser window? I can't reproduce them in standalone IE. There is no F12 developer tools in Outlook, as far as I can tell.

For now, the problem is that icon fonts are not displayed in Outlook Folder Web Page browser window, while they are in IE, and I am trying to find the issue step-by-step.

Comment: Outlook uses Word to render HTML. The supported feature set is so dumbed down that you can give up right now, `@font-face` is not among them.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, it has no problem parsing all the 2MB of javascript framework and displaying nearly everything correctly; and it tells me that it `document.documentMode` is `11`, which seems to be IE11 specific, not Word specific. Just the icon font is not displayed. Do you have any source to back up your claim?

Comment: Hm, I refer to the mode that Outlook uses to display HTML emails. That it even looks at JS would be news to me. So I guess you must be talking about something else.

Comment: Which Outlook browser do you mean? Outlook Today or folder web page? Preview pane? Inspector?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Folder Web Page. Didn't know the others even existed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Folder home page uses IE to render its contents ("Internet Explorer_Server").
Did you point the page to a network location? Or a resource file?